# What does the `array` keyword mean in the parameter list of a PHP function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameters

```
function request($suffix, array $post = array(), $action = NULL) {
    // do something...
}
```

I saw a function in a book. But I don't understand what the keyword `array` means before `$post` in the parameter list of the function. I feel that omitting the `array` will have the same effect.

Does it act as a data type prompt? If so, then why can't I use `string`, `integer` etc before other parameters?

Comment: It means that the parameter `$post` **must be** an array. It will throw an error if it's not an array.

Comment: I believe in php 7.0 they introduced a more strict way of inputting data. The array before $post would throw an error and enable proper handling if a function is being used incorrectly.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't that code contradictory? It forces the parameter to be an array (using the keyword) but makes it and optional array by adding `= array()`.

Comment: There is no error. There is no difference. So I just wonder what the functionality of the keyword `array` is. @bub

Comment: _There is no error._ There is a fatal error if you call the method with "worng" parameters

Comment: @Script47 the array _type_ is not optional but you can use the method without passing an array, so it will be an empty array as defined in the method header

Comment: @bub ah, essentially it is optional as a default value is provided though. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Script47 exactly. you welcome

Comment: Then why there's only the `array` prompt to limit the data type to be Array in PHP, while there are no other prompts to limit other types, such as `integer`, `string` etc.? (If I use `integer`, `string` etc., I'll get syntax error prompts in IDE.) @Jer

Comment: Then why there's only the `array` prompt to limit the data type to be Array in PHP, while there are no other prompts to limit other types, such as `integer`, `string` etc.? (If I use `integer`, `string` etc., I'll get syntax error prompts in IDE.) @bub

Comment: @Benson he could have used **request(int $suffix, array $post = array(), $action = NULL)**

Comment: I can't use `int` or `integer` before a parameter. If I do so, I'll get an syntax error prompt in my IDE. @bub

Comment: @Benson it is a feature of PHP 7, maybe you are using lower versions

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP 5.6, not PHP 7. @bub

Comment: @Benson PHP 5 only introducted type hinting for classes, interfaces and arrays, primitive type hinting is only available since php 7.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! My confusion was resolved now. @xander

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function request($suffix, array $post = array(), $action = NULL) {
    // do something...
}
```

That function accepts number of parameters, parameter $post is type hinted to array

```
array $post = array()
```

here we can see that $post is assigned an empty array as default, so it is conforming to its type

```
$post = array() and array $post = array() will return the same
```

if you try to pass something else than an array as an argument to that function you will get errors

[type hinting](https://www.sitepoint.com/type-hinting-in-php/) refer to that for more explanation

Comment: Thank you very much! Then I just wonder that why there's only the `array` type hinting to limit the data type to be Array in PHP, while there are no other type hinting to limit other types, such as `integer`, `string` etc.? (If I use `integer`, `string` etc., I'll get syntax error prompts in IDE. I'm using PHP 5.6.)

Comment: Do note, that in PHP5 this type hint would be interpreted as requiring the first argument to be an instance of the class “string” not a string. As a result in PHP5, passing a string to the class written this way would cause an error. In PHP7 a string is required. - Source: https://torquemag.io/2016/09/wordpress-developers-guide-type-hinting/ @Benson

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: Thank you for your helpful instructions!

Comment: Wonderful. Now I understand. Thank you so much! @Cezary